# Extract part of text in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, search, match

This is my input file which is random, can be any number not just 9999 and any letters:
The below format will always come after a `-` (dash).

```
-
9999 99AKDSLY9ZWSRK99999
9999 99BGRPOE99FTRQ99999
```

Expected output:

```
AKDSLY9ZSRK
BGRPOE99TRQ
```

So I need to remove the first part of each line, always numbers:

```
9999 99
9999 99
```

Then remove the not-required characters:

`99AKDSLY9ZW` → in this case is the `W` but could be any letter
`99BGRPOE99F` → in this case is the `F` but could be any letter

And finally remove the last 5 digits, always numbers:

```
99999
99999
```

What I´m trying to use, regex (first time using it):

```
$result = [regex]::Matches($InputFile, '(^\d{4}\s\d{2}[A-Z0-9]\d{5}$)') -replace '\d{4}\s\d{2}', '')
$result
```

It's not giving me an error message but it's not showing me the characters I'm expecting to see at `$result`.

I was expecting to see something in `$result` to then start the formatting, deleting the characters I don't need.

What could be missing here, please?

Comment: Generalize it. `^[\d ]*(.+?)[\d ]*$` replace `$1`, then `Then remove the not-required characters` in a separate regex operation. Set multi-line mode for both regex operations.

Comment: Your regular expression says `start of string, four digits, space, two digits, a single letter or number, five digits, end of string` - because of the single letter or number, it will never match anything. (and even if you change it to match, the match would be the entire line, which makes it useless) `'9999 99BGRPOE99FTRQ99999' -replace '^\d{4} \d{2}|\d{5}$' -replace '.(?=...$)'` to replace the start or the end numbers, then replace the fourth-from-last-character (my best guess as to why you are chosing the W and F...)

Comment: the W and F are extra characters that come randomly with the input file and need to be deleted so this file can be consumed by another application, otherwise, if characters are not removed, validation will fail. I´m trying both ways shared here, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$str = (Get-Content ... -Raw) -replace '\r'

$cb = {
  $args[0].Groups[1].Value -replace '(?m)^.{7}' -replace '(?m).(.{3}).{5}$', '$1'
}

$re = [regex]'(?m)^(?<=-\n)((?:\d{4}\s\d{2}[^\n]*\d{5}(?:\n|$))+)'

$re.Replace($str, $cb)
```

The regular expression `$re` matches multiline substrings that start with a hyphen and a newline, followed by one or more line with your digit/letter combinations. The `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind assertion to ensure that you only get a match when the lines with the digit/letter combinations are preceded by a line with a hyphen (without making that line part of the actual match).

The scriptblock `$cb` is an anonymous callback function that the `Regex.Replace()` method calls on each match. For each line in a match it removes the first 7 characters from the beginning of the line, and replaces the last 9 characters from the end of the line with the 2nd through 4th of those characters.

For simplicity reasons the sample code removes carriage return characters (CR, `\r`) from the string, so that all newlines are linefeed characters (LF, `\n`) instead of the default CR-LF.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, this is a very nice explanation about the regex usage. I´ve tried this and works perfectly checking the results at console, when I output the file using | Out-File it shows everything at same line, like a text without carriage return. If I comment out this part `-replace '\r'`, it does not work either, kind of tricky.

Comment: Split the string at newlines before piping the result to `Out-File`. If you want to keep the CR in the input string you need to adjust the regular expression to account for the additional characters.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! Thanks @Ansgar Wiechers. And I´ve got to learn a little bit more about PowerShell, especially about regex.